# unable to run java -jar but can do java-cp

Tags: java, jar

I'm unable to run a java jar file it shows the error -

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.tgbot.telegrambot.Bota
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/exceptions/TelegramApiException
```

I'm using the command -

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib/ -jar TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But I'm able to run the jar file using the cp command -

```
java -cp TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/* com.tgbot.telegrambot.Bota
```

Comment: So the JAR file doesn’t have a complete Class-Path entry in the Manifest. `java -jar` ignores all other classpaths.

Comment: <Class-Path>lib</Class-Path> in pom.xml still same error

Comment: So, as @user207421 suggests, unless you've fixed up a classpath (which would probably have several jars) inside the manifest, you'd be looking a a 'fat jar' to be able to invoke only one jar if you have dependencies

Comment: now i removed addclasspath and class-path entry but still it ignores -Djava.library.path

Comment: *... but still it ignores -Djava.library.path* What makes you think that? And note that has nothing to do with the *reported* error

Comment: I didn’t say anything about pom.xml. I mentioned the Manifest.

Comment: IMO messing with jars in Class-Path in a manifest rather defeats the object of packaging your app as an executable jar. If you can't relocate it arbitrarily without shifting a lot of other jars in that Class-Path entry too (barring absolute paths), you might as well use `-cp`. So, either do just that or make a fat jar

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html) of the `java` tool: "When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored."

Comment: (and `java.library.path` is **not** used for loading classes)

Comment: <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix> solves all problems. I also don't know how i dug it up from maven documentation.

Answer (score 0):

classpathprefix solves the problem in maven's pom.xml

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
      <mainClass>com.tgbot.telegrambot.Bota</mainClass>                            
    </manifest>
```

Now i can simply run -

```
java -jar TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```